# 'svn+ssh10401' hangs where plain 'ssh' works, failing to go to 'protocol 2.0'

Tags: svn, ssh, freeze, tunnel

Tunneling through ssh on a non-standard port, as I must run svn on my remote server on port 10401 (it's 'svnserve'), I get a hang right before where log lines about protocol 2.0 should be:

Local box uname: Linux localbox 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Remote box unname (server name changed to 'foo'): Linux foo 2.6.32.27-grsec #5 SMP Thu Dec 30 01:24:01 PST 2010 i686 unknown unknown GNU/Linux

```
christopherbalz@localbox:~$ svn co --username=christopherbalz svn+ssh10401://foo.bar.com/baz

OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/christopherbalz/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for foo.bar.com
debug1: Applying options for foo.bar.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to foo.bar.com [208.95.105.37] port 10401.
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /home/christopherbalz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/christopherbalz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/christopherbalz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/christopherbalz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

< hangs here forever >
```

By contrast, a plain ssh to this server gives the same log as above plus this (and more, not pasted here) directly after, right where the log hangs above:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
. . .
```

Since the 'protocol 2.0' logs come directly after, I wonder if under svn+ssh there is some issue with the compatibility mode mentioned in the logs?  If so, how to troubleshoot that?  If not, what might be causing this hang?